# Branching in arm assembly

Tags: assembly, arm, functions, register

This is an example assembly code:

```
     function0()
 0x0.mov r0, #1
 0x8.mov r1, #20
0x10.mov r2, #6
0x18.cmp r1, #16
0x20.b function1

     function1()
0x28.cmp r0, #1
0x30.b functionX

     functionX()
0x38.bx lr
```

As far as I know, `function0` moved those values into the first 3 registers. In `function1` no values were moved into registers.

What I don't understand is:

1. after branching to `function1` do registers `r1` and `r2` still have those values or those registers have been zeroed out?
2. After branching to `functionX`, is the link register still the same as the one in function0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you confuse between functions and blocks. It looks like what you call `function0`, `function1` and `functionX` are in fact parts of the same function, and just different basic blocks within the function.

To your specific questions:

1. Nothing changes `r0`, `r1`, and `r2` between `0x20.b function1` and `0x28.cmp r0 #1`. So yes, they still hold the values from what you called `function0`. There is nothing in the code, or in assembly as general that implicitly zero out all registers.
2. This is the place where the lr is fetched, and jumped to - it is supposed to hold the value of the caller function - The instruction after the call to what you called `function0`. the `lr` didn't change between what you called `function0`, `function1` and `functionX`.

Comment: Since you mentioned functions an blocks, would there be a difference if those functions were actually 3 different functions and not blocks from the same function?

Comment: About the first question - there will be no difference. About the second - the `lr` will change on each call (assuming `call` instruction is used, instead of `b`)